# ¿Cómo llamar una clase en la clase main?

Tags: java, netbeans

Soy muy nuevo en Java y estoy practicando con Clases.
Tengo el siguiente código el cual es operación del método húngaro.

```
package metodohungaro;

public class HungarianDouble {
    private int[][] originalValues; // Given values
    private int[][] values; // Cloned given values to be processed
    private int[][] lines; // Line drawn
    private int numLines; // Number of line drawn

    int rows[]; // Index of the column selected by every row (The final result)
    int occupiedCols[]; // Verify that all column are occupied, used in the optimization step

    public HungarianDouble(int[][] matrix) {
        // Initialization
        originalValues = matrix; // Given matrix
        values = cloneMatrix(matrix); // Cloned matrix to be processed
        rows = new int[values.length];
        occupiedCols = new int[values.length];

        //Algorithm
        subtractRowMinimal();               // Step 1
        subtractColMinimal();               // Step 2
        coverZeros();                       // Step 3
        while(numLines < values.length){
            createAdditionalZeros();        // Step 4 (Condition)
            coverZeros();                   // Step 3 Again (Condition)
        }
        optimization();                     // Optimization
    }

    /**
     * Step 1
     * Subtract from every element the minimum value from its row
     * */
    public void subtractRowMinimal(){
        int rowMinValue[] = new int[values.length];
        //get the minimum for each row and store in rowMinValue[]
        for(int row=0; row<values.length;row++){
            rowMinValue[row] = values[row][0];
            for(int col=1; col<values.length;col++){
                if(values[row][col] < rowMinValue[row])
                    rowMinValue[row] = values[row][col];
            }
        }

        //subtract minimum from each row using rowMinValue[]
        for(int row=0; row<values.length;row++){
            for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){
                values[row][col] -= rowMinValue[row];
            }
        }
    } //End Step 1

    /**
     * Step 2
     * Subtract from every element the minimum value from its column
     * */
    public void subtractColMinimal(){
        int colMinValue[] = new int[values.length];
        //get the minimum for each column and store them in colMinValue[]
        for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){
            colMinValue[col] = values[0][col];
            for(int row=1; row<values.length;row++){
                if(values[row][col] < colMinValue[col])
                    colMinValue[col] = values[row][col];
            }
        }

        //subtract minimum from each column using colMinValue[]
        for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){
            for(int row=0; row<values.length;row++){
                values[row][col] -= colMinValue[col];
            }
        }
    } //End Step 2

    /**
     * Step 3.1
     * Loop through all elements, and run colorNeighbors when the element visited is equal to zero
     * */
    public void coverZeros(){
        numLines = 0;
        lines = new int[values.length][values.length];

        for(int row=0; row<values.length;row++){
            for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){
                if(values[row][col] == 0)
                    colorNeighbors(row, col, maxVH(row, col));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Step 3.2
     * Checks which direction (vertical,horizontal) contains more zeros, every time a zero is found vertically, we increment the result
     * and every time a zero is found horizontally, we decrement the result. At the end, result will be negative, zero or positive
     * @param row Row index for the target cell
     * @param col Column index for the target cell
     * @return Positive integer means that the line passing by indexes [row][col] should be vertical, Zero or Negative means that the line passing by indexes [row][col] should be horizontal
     * */
    private int maxVH(int row, int col){
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<values.length;i++){
            if(values[i][col] == 0)
                result++;
            if(values[row][i] == 0)
                result--;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Step 3.3
     * Color the neighbors of the cell at index [row][col]. To know which direction to draw the lines, we pass maxVH value.
     * @param row Row index for the target cell
     * @param col Column index for the target cell
     * @param maxVH Value return by the maxVH method, positive means the line to draw passing by indexes [row][col] is vertical, negative or zero means the line to draw passing by indexes [row][col] is horizontal
     * */
    private void colorNeighbors(int row, int col, int maxVH){
        if(lines[row][col] == 2) // if cell is colored twice before (intersection cell), don't color it again
            return;

        if(maxVH > 0 && lines[row][col] == 1) // if cell colored vertically and needs to be recolored vertically, don't color it again (Allowing this step, will color the same line (result won't change), but the num of line will be incremented (wrong value for the num of line drawn))
            return;

        if(maxVH <= 0 && lines[row][col] == -1) // if cell colored horizontally and needs to be recolored horizontally, don't color it again (Allowing this step, will color the same line (result won't change), but the num of line will be incremented (wrong value for the num of line drawn))
            return;

        for(int i=0; i<values.length;i++){ // Loop on cell at indexes [row][col] and its neighbors
            if(maxVH > 0)   // if value of maxVH is positive, color vertically
                lines[i][col] = lines[i][col] == -1 || lines[i][col] == 2 ? 2 : 1; // if cell was colored before as horizontal (-1), and now needs to be colored vertical (1), so this cell is an intersection (2). Else if this value was not colored before, color it vertically
            else            // if value of maxVH is zero or negative color horizontally
                lines[row][i] = lines[row][i] == 1 || lines[row][i] == 2 ? 2 : -1; // if cell was colored before as vertical (1), and now needs to be colored horizontal (-1), so this cell is an intersection (2). Else if this value was not colored before, color it horizontally
        }

        // increment line number
        numLines++;
//      printMatrix(lines); // Monitor the line draw steps
    }//End step 3

    /**
     * Step 4
     * This step is not always executed. (Check the algorithm in the constructor)
     * Create additional zeros, by coloring the minimum value of uncovered cells (cells not colored by any line)
     * */
    public void createAdditionalZeros(){
        int minUncoveredValue = 0; // We don't know the value of the first uncovered cell, so we put a joker value 0 (0 is safe, because before this step, all zeros were covered)

        // Find the min in the uncovered numbers
        for(int row=0; row<values.length;row++){
            for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){
                if(lines[row][col] == 0 && (values[row][col] < minUncoveredValue || minUncoveredValue == 0))
                    minUncoveredValue = values[row][col];
            }
        }

        // Subtract min form all uncovered elements, and add it to all elements covered twice
        for(int row=0; row<values.length;row++){
            for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){
                if(lines[row][col] == 0) // If uncovered, subtract
                    values[row][col] -= minUncoveredValue;

                else if(lines[row][col] == 2) // If covered twice, add
                    values[row][col] += minUncoveredValue;
            }
        }
    } // End step 4

    /**
     * Optimization, assign every row a cell in a unique column. Since a row can contain more than one zero,
     * we need to make sure that all rows are assigned one cell from one unique column. To do this, use brute force
     * @param row
     * @param boolean If all rows were assigned a cell from a unique column, return true (at the end, guarantee true)
     * @return true
     * */
    private boolean optimization(int row){
        if(row == rows.length) // If all rows were assigned a cell
            return true;

        for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){ // Try all columns
            if(values[row][col] == 0 && occupiedCols[col] == 0){ // If the current cell at column `col` has a value of zero, and the column is not reserved by a previous row
                rows[row] = col; // Assign the current row the current column cell
                occupiedCols[col] = 1; // Mark the column as reserved
                if(optimization(row+1)) // If the next rows were assigned successfully a cell from a unique column, return true
                    return true;
                occupiedCols[col] = 0; // If the next rows were not able to get a cell, go back and try for the previous rows another cell from another column
            }
        }
        return false; // If no cell were assigned for the current row, return false to go back one row to try to assign to it another cell from another column
    }

    /**
     * Overload optimization(int row) method
     * @return true
     * */
    public boolean optimization(){
        return optimization(0);
    } //End optimization

    /**
     * Get the result by returning an array containing the cell assigned for each row
     * @return Array of rows where each array index represent the row number, and the value at each index is the column assigned to the corresponding row
     * */
    public int[] getResult(){
        return rows;
    }

    /**
     * Get the sum of the value of the assigned cells for all rows using the original passed matrix, and using the rows array to know the index of the column for each row.
     * @return Total values
     * */
    public double getTotal(){
        double total = 0;
        for(int row = 0; row < values.length; row++)
            total += originalValues[row][rows[row]];
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * Clone the 2D array
     * @return A copy of the 2D array
     * */
    public int[][] cloneMatrix(int[][] matrix){
        int[][] tmp = new int[matrix.length][matrix.length];
        for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
            tmp[row] = matrix[row].clone();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Print a 2D array
     * @param matrix The target 2D array
     * */
    public void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
        for(int row=0; row<matrix.length;row++){
            for(int col=0; col<matrix.length;col++){
                System.out.print(matrix[row][col]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo llamar esta clase en main para poder correr correr el programa, teniendo dada ya la matriz.

```
package metodohungaro;

public class MetodoHungaro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] mas = {{14,5,8,7}, {2, 12, 6, 5}, {7,8,3,9}, {2,4,6,10}};
        HungarianDouble method = new HungarianDouble(mas);
    }   
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el objeto `HungarianDouble` si se esta ejecutando, lo unico es que dentro de el no estas imprimiendo nada en consola, lo que da la impresion de que no esta sucediendo nada.

Si te fijas, en el metodo `colorNeighbors()` tienes la linea que se encarga de imprimir los resultados en consola comentada.

```
// printMatrix(lines);
```

Y como ya debes saber, las lineas comentadas se omiten al ejecutar el programa.

Para ver los resultados que generta el programa, es simple, solo tienes que quitarle el comentario a esa linea.

```
private void colorNeighbors(int row, int col, int maxVH){

    ...

    printMatrix(lines);
}
```

---

Otras correcciones:

1. Seria, como llamar un objeto en la clase main. Las clases son como las plantillas de los objetos, al momento de instanciarlas, llamas a los objetos y no a las clases. Es bueno tener los conceptos claros desde un principio, eso te evitara unos cuantos dolores de cabeza en un futuro.
2. Si dices que eres nuevo en Java, porque utilizas ejemplos tan complejos, si te soy sincero apenas entendí el funcionamiento de la clase `HungarianDouble`. Cuando publiques otra pregunta ten en cuenta explicar el funcionamiento de las clases, de esa manera es mas fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

La clase main se ejecuta automáticamente cuando le das a el botón de run projet (que es como el de start) si trabajas con un IDE como netbeans o eclipse. Este botón es la típica flecha hacia la derecha en un reproductor de video o sonido.

También puedes ejecutarlo en el menú de "run" arriba a la izquierda.

¡Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Sí, yo se esto, pero al correr el programa corre bien sin error pero no aparece nada de la operación, quisiera saber como llamar a la clase HungarianDouble para que resuelva la operación .

Comment: Ah! disculpa, no te había entendido. Como bien ha dicho Panbo, para llamar a una función desde el main debe ser static.

¿Esta tu función en diferentes clases o en la misma?

Answer (score 0):

En un mismo programa no puede haber dos métodos main, solo uno, entonces, la segunda clase quedaría así(aproximadamente):

```
 package metodohungaro;

    public class MetodoHungaro {

    public static HungarianDouble calcular(int[][] mas) {
        HungarianDouble method = new HungarianDouble(mas);
        //puedes devolver otra cosa si quieres
        return method;
    }   
}
```

Luego puedes llamarlo desde el Main así:

```
HungarianDouble resultado = MetodoHungaro.calcular(mas);
```

No conozco la clase HungarianDouble, pero puedes jugar con los parámetros que pasas y con lo que devuelves, si la clase HungarianDouble tiene un método para devolver un double, puedes hacer un return de eso mejor, en este caso al llamar al método sería asi:

```
    package metodohungaro;

    public class MetodoHungaro {

    public static HungarianDouble calcular(int[][] mas) {
        HungarianDouble method = new HungarianDouble(mas);
        double resultado = method.metodoQueDevuelveUnDouble();
        return resultado;
    }   
}
```

En este caso se llamaría asi:

```
double resultado = MetodoHungaro.calcular(mas);
```